# Safari Reader support for code

Tags: safari

Is there a Safari extension that can better display code in reader view?

Original on webpage:

[image]

In reader view:

[image]

Any way to better format code in reader view?

Comment: Except the '* img' going to the next line, what's wrong with current view?

Comment: The code just looks like regular text, is there anyway to make it more distinguishable from the rest of the english text?